# Exending YouTubeBaseActivity throws java.lang.ClassCastException:

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

Hey Everyone I am developing an application that plays YouTube Video, I extend YoutubeBaseActivity for the activity that should play the video but I keep getting an error when the activity is reached. Below is log cat error.

```
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{org.dclmhq.streamingapp/com.dclmhq.disuplytbvid.PlaySelectedVideo}:  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dclmhq.disuplytbvid.PlaySelectedVideo cannot be cast to com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer$OnInitializedListener
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dclmhq.disuplytbvid.PlaySelectedVideo cannot be cast to com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer$OnInitializedListener
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at com.dclmhq.disuplytbvid.PlaySelectedVideo.onCreate(PlaySelectedVideo.java:33)
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
04-30 09:11:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    ... 11 more
```

Here is my code

```
    public class PlaySelectedVideo extends YouTubeBaseActivity {


MediaPlayer mPlayer;
Intent receInt;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playyoutubevideo);
    receInt = getIntent();
    TextView titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerTitle);
    TextView descView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerDesc);
    titleView.setText(receInt.getStringExtra("com.xxx.disuplytbvid.TITLE"));
    descView.setText(receInt.getStringExtra("com.xxx.disuplytbvid.DESCRIPTION"));
    YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youTubeView.initialize(API_KEY, (YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener)this);

    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

}


  public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
      boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
      String id = receInt.getStringExtra("com.XXX.disuplytbvid.vID");
      player.cueVideo(id);
    }
  }


  protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
  }
```

And my Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:id="@+id/playerTitle"
  android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:text="@string/playerview_title"/>
  <TextView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:id="@+id/playerDesc"
  android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:text="@string/playerview_desc"/>    
 </LinearLayout>


 <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
  android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extend not only

```
YouTubeBaseActivity but also Implement YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener
```

and implement the reequired Methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try **YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity** instead of **YouTubeBaseActivity** for extending your **PlaySelectedVideo** activity.

and instead of this

```
youTubeView.initialize("AIzaSyAYBzv-h4SrKw16L-IXczrkXkVeX21fyU8", (YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener)this);
```

try

```
youTubeView.initialize("AIzaSyAYBzv-h4SrKw16L-IXczrkXkVeX21fyU8", YouTubeBaseActivity.this);
```